# Best way to display an image in a shape

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can anybody tell me which is the best way to display an image like this?

[image]

Comment: With background-image

Comment: The best way is just to cut the image out in this shape, as a PNG with a transparent background. Any methods for doing this with css won't be well supported

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to do it, you just have to assess the various degrees of browser support for each:

CSS Masks do this really well:

http://thenittygritty.co/css-masking

But I think they probably have the worst browser support.

I believe you can also do masking with SVG, but SVG isn't supported all that well anyways either, and has a bit of learning curve to it.

The way I would probably do it would be with a hacky little use of `transform: rotate()`;

```
.image-shape {
    height: 150px;
    background: url(http://imagz.inspiredmagz.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/3D-Illustrations-by-JR-Schmidt-08.jpg);
    position: relative;
}
.image-shape .point {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25px;
    right: -25px;
    background: #777;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.image-shape .point img {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    position: absolute;
    top: -275px;
    left: -85px;
}
```

Where you have a div with the background image set, and then another div rotated 45 degrees and positioned to form the 'point' at the bottom. Inside this you put the image, rotate that back 45 degrees and position it to line up with the background image of the first div. (positioning it is a pain, because of the rotations, but as long as this doesnt need to scale, once you do it it's good to go.

The additional parts of the image are cut off by setting `overflow: hidden;` on the point div, and then again on a main container div around all of this.

See this fiddle for the html and the rest of the css:

http://jsfiddle.net/BszC3/

The reason that I would use this method is because rotation is relatively well supported, and can be achieved in IE with their proprietary filters:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(sizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476); /* IE6,IE7 */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod='auto expand', M11=0.7071067811865476, M12=-0.7071067811865475, M21=0.7071067811865475, M22=0.7071067811865476)"; /* IE8 */
```

The downside is that it's a fair bit of work, and seems like a total hack.

Your best bet is still just to cut your image out like this and not bother with any crazy CSS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `html5` canvas:

http://jsfiddle.net/HDqE8/

An alternative without html5 is using a masking image (an image with a transparent part in the middle, with the shape you like, and the rest with the background color). Then you just have to overlap the 2 images and put the first on top. The image could be also an svg.